# Can a flow be terminated if a specific task fails?

Tags: etl, prefect

I have a long flow and I would like to mark its state as `Failed` if a *specific* task fails.

I read the docs [here](https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/states.html#overview), however they don't seem to specify such a scenario.
My guess is that I need to specific this somehow in the `@task()` decorator, but I don't know how.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by declaring your specific task a "reference task" of your Flow.  [Reference tasks](https://docs.prefect.io/core/getting_started/next-steps.html#reference-tasks) are the tasks that ultimately determine the final state for each flow run.

For example, the following code snippet creates a flow with two independent, unrelated tasks that random fail half the time.  However, the overall flow run state will only be determined based on the state of `task_one`, as we specify that task as the sole reference task:

```py
import random
from prefect import task, Flow


@task
def task_one():
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        raise ValueError("Random failure")

@task
def task_two():
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        raise ValueError("Random failure")


flow = Flow("Two Task Flow", tasks=[task_one, task_two])
flow.set_reference_tasks([task_one])
```

Comment: Hi @chriswhite, so this answer determines the flow state. However if the tasks were related in one big DAG, then will this stop the Flow if I set a reference task in the middle of the flow and if that task were to fail?

Comment: Unfortunately not at this time, although I can see that use case.  If you are using an API backend, you could create a task state handler that calls `cancel_flow_run` if the reference task fails, which will achieve similar (although not identical) behavior

Comment: Cool thanks. I will submit this as a feature request.